# How to set a endpoint on a Spring Web Service using Ajax receiving JSON

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot, endpoint

I was unable to find an answer to this but I am trying to figure out how to change the endpoint of this Spring Web Service.  I know NOTHING about them and so I have copied [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ajax-example/) as an example to try. But I do not want to run this from `https://localhost:8080`.  I would prefer to run it from anywhere but root such as `https://localhost/service/healthcheck` or whatever.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add the path at the rest controller anotation `@RestController("service")
public class SearchController {` your method should be named `@PostMapping("healthcheck")`

Comment: Yep, that changes the calling endpoints but does that also change where the index.html file gets loaded from?  I guess that's what I'm asking.  Since there is no web.xml file how can I do that in this scenario?

Comment: @jnbbender can you update your question based off of the above? The first comment would solve your question but if you are looking for something more specific, please edit your question with the exact path you are looking for in regards to index.html.